# I want Samba to set modification time of a file from server, not client

Tags: samba

I've a samba share I use to access files from a client. When a file is saved by the client, I need the modification time to be updated for the file by the server's time, not the client's time. Suppose that both systems vary in time by some seconds, one is behind another for some seconds. When opening the folder in VSCode, I get the message indicating that the file is newer than what I've edited and this is because the client time is some seconds before the server's time. Every time, I've to run ntpdate on the server for the problem to get resolved. Or I should use Overwrite button to forcefully replace its content. But if samba may isolate the client time from server time, the problem doesn't occur. That is when writing to a shared file, it assumes the server's time and saves it as the file's modification time. Although I don't know how to handle the file time when it's read.
Anyway, I thought samba might have such an option, but since I couldn't find it, I come here to ask.

Comment: How exactly are the clients saving the files to the samba share?

Comment: Why are your clocks not automatically synced?

Comment: @Layne: The shared folder is opened in vscode and is treated with as a local folder.

Comment: @Michael: Why should they be synced?! how? They're two separate systems.

Comment: Using NTP, of course. And why is obvious.

Comment: In that case the best workaround would probably be to either set up a script to automatically 'touch' files on the server when they are modified, to overwrite the mtime, or else to just make sure both client and server have the time synced via NTP or equivalent. I don't think samba has an such flag to use server time - generally it depends on how you're copying it which is why I asked. For example you should be able to use the "preserve time" flag (-t) with rsync to achieve what you are looking for, but you would have to rsync the files. You may want to see if that is an option within vscode.

Comment: @LayneBernardo There's no copy operation! The files are located on the server and accessed via samba from the location without being copied to client or somewhere else!

Comment: @MichaelHampton An option is to sync client's time with server's time. This is not a good idea. Because I prefer to sync client's time with a public time server. The server's time should be synced with a public time server too to hold a correct time. What I asked was about "an option in samba", not a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's what I'm saying - one solution would be to work on the files locally and then rsync them to the remote share using the appropriate flags, *instead of* working directly in the remote folder. Or else 'touch' the files server-side when you detect a modification (this would have to be implemented separately).

Comment: I'm not sure how much it's practical with lots of files in the folder. Especially, when there's .git folder with lots of files and many temp files. I hope ntp daemon may workaround the problem. My original question was, whether samba has such an option? instead of is there a workaround for this problem?